# How important is it to brush infant's teeth before vs. after the goodnight milk bottle?

Tags: infant, bedtime, brushing-teeth

My little guy gets a bottle as the last thing before we put him to bed, it greatly helps him to wind down and relax for sleep. As the teeth start coming, we realize it's important to brush his teeth, but this wakes him up and makes it difficult to put him to bed afterward.

It would probably be easier to brush his teeth before giving him the milk, but I know we'd be trading dental hygiene for a bit of convenience for the parents.

How do we handle this dilemma?

Comment: How old is he? If the teeth only started to come it might be much too early to even brush teeth.

Comment: @Guillaume: He's around 1 year old, but the advice generally is to brush any teeth that are there. So it's not too early.

Comment: and you have tried giving him sweet water with a sugar substitute instead of milk? Does that not work?

Comment: @user462608: Why in the world would I want to give him sugar before sleep? No, he's getting 180mL _food_ so he can sleep through the night.

Comment: I said "sugar substitute" with water so that he doesn't ask for sweet milk. Okay, I didn't know that a "sugar substitute" is as harmful as sugar w.r.t tooth decay.

Comment: My niece is 3, and we have exactly the same question. (Well, sippy cup instead of bottle, but same idea.) It doesn't help that this child and sleep are mortal enemies.

Answer (score 6):

This might make your life simpler (or possibly more worrying, considering how long you may have been doing this wrong): You're supposed to [brush **before** meals](http://www.rdhmag.com/articles/print/volume-24/issue-2/columns/periodontics/brush-before-eating.html). It's [technically harmful to brush immediately after](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/dentalhealth/Pages/Teethcleaningguide.aspx), as it removes acid softened enamel.

Brushing removes plaque, not food, so you actually want to brush the plaque off before eating, as it immediately produces acid when the food hits it, so most of the damage is done to your teeth well before you brush... the softened enamel of your teeth away, increasing the damage.

**So, there you go, you simply get him to brush at the *start* of his bedtime routine, then story, then bottle, then sleep.**

**Sources:** The Dental Hygenist magazine and the NHS guidance on teeth cleaning.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting!

Comment: It's also worth noting (and this is anecdotally from a dentist) that for 3mths - 1year, all they're really looking for is a decent coating of flouride on the teeth, as the chances of you managing to properly brush an 1 year old's teeth the way you're supposed to are Zero.

Comment: @deworde I knew that about ingesting acid beverages (like sodas, some juices), that you should wait some minutes allowing your saliva recompose the pH inside your mouth.

Comment: @deworde Wait, what?! You give 3-month-olds fluoride?!  We were told to wipe the teeth with a wet clean washcloth.

Comment: @Charles we're advised to use fluoride toothpaste to help keep the teeth healthy once they've broken through the surface of the gums, but to keep it to pea sized amounts, good guidance here, on NHS website: http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/dentalhealth/Pages/Careofkidsteeth.aspx

Comment: @deworde: how on earth do you get a 3-month-old to spit out the (highly poisonous if swallowed) fluoride toothpaste?

Comment: The simple answer is, you don't. [The more complex answer is that the levels of fluoride in toothpaste are well below the toxicity level in the pea-sized quantity on a toothbrush and will get excreted out. Obviously you monitor your child for ill-effects and consult a paediatrician in the event of illness.](http://health.howstuffworks.com/wellness/oral-care/kids/what-if-child-eats-fluoride-toothpaste.htm) Also, children's toothpaste has less fluoride (assuming legitimate company, use judgement)

That said, if they down a tube of it, emergency room, so keep it out of their reach.

Comment: We use tiny tiny grains of toothpaste for our 8 month year old.

Answer (score 2):

With the baby teeth, we did morning and evening brushing, whenever we could. If they had a bottle later on at night (eg 2am) we wouldn't try and wake them to brush.

Once they would sleep for a good portion of the night we would play a game at bedtime that included brushing after their night time bottle.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not a parent, so this is not based on experience.</sub>

Since deworde already [answered](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/9173/30519) the question about *when* to brush teeth, I want to add a possible solution to your other question:

> How do we handle this dilemma?

Dental hygiene is important to you, but you are reluctant to wake your infant up after the nighttime bottle. And after drinking milk and without brushing teeth, there will be food left in the infant's mouth during the night.

Then, what about an alternative to brushing, that removes the food? It's safer than no brushing at all, without having the downsides of brushing right after eating or waking them later at night.

> Water, however, cleans your mouth with every sip. It washes away leftover food and residue that cavity-causing bacteria are looking for. It also dilutes the acids produced by the bacteria in your mouth. You’ll still need to brush twice a day for two minutes and clean between your teeth, but drinking water through the day will go a long way toward keeping your smile cavity-free.

*Source:* [4 Reasons Water Is the Best Beverage for Your Teeth](https://www.mouthhealthy.org/en/nutrition/food-tips/water-best-beverage), ADA (American Dental Association)

So after the nighttime bottle, you could try to make the infant sip a bit of plain water to remove most of the milk (and sugar etc.) from the teeth. Try to find a good amount of it, so that it's not too much (maybe a mouthful).